# « Une bonne fois, si tu veux / Je te montrerai sans tricher un côté de moi » : sens de « une bonne fois » ?

Tags: sens, adverbes, locutions, québec, paroles-de-chanson

> *T'es Mon Amour, T'es Ma Maîtresse*
>
> T'es mon amour, je suis ta maîtresse
>  T'es tout ce que je veux,
> t'es tout ce que j'ai voulu
>  T'es mon amour de la tête aux
> fesses
>  Et plus ça va, et plus t'es mon amie
>
> **Une bonne fois**, si tu veux
>  Je te montrerai sans tricher un côté de moi
>  Comme je n'ai jamais osé montrer
>  À qui que ce
> soit
> [...]
>
> [Jean-pierre Ferland](https://youtu.be/fBWuuno7-rI) / Jean Pierre Paquin

Dans ces paroles (ou ces exemples : [1](https://www.campingquebec.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33201&start=15&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=6967a1210702a175fd809055d23fa9c400a54357-1612431401-0-AfzwKdMGlM71vblEK7gpmv4rrj0gaZ4PCLp0kqtXpeBLDHpXDSanabRvVIjLyq54x_pJn36mP-4JXURKZ9YuB4B0W4UVpZbVpuyx1uU7nym-4sCPacZxbSyKn9F0ihJaM_ocM4altIBZT9yMsLftxs-c_1LpkdVCCPx5ycC9zRZTCklyczkyQ--ljjuMZ4nUQhBbYtrnW99-zWeRofCa4dW3l2w8MB7P56TJprARMNAYoCS-Rj8ZeaEDW4gjTwIXHMFkWXcxKAs95bVMtaYHe2dUrTKINCsLsCuVgX1Gj5KiFxMikvNTswi98O4t7uRIaR0HCHliuxPLSBgh-C1EwDoDI9cGh-mcCvnNKfypGZ3gVddpo39rDYw_eg7jqb3WqeM1HJaEGk1f8Uighh-Xppq8DMyapke8HX6QsuXcESs6), [2](https://quebecfrancais.org/sprechen-sie-deutsch-lallemagne-defend-sa-langue-2/), [3](https://vinquebec.com/node/6637), [4](https://www.quebecloisirs.com/accueil/un-printemps-ardent-fl00111639.html), [5](https://lecahier.com/bienvenue-a-montreal-une-nouvelle-webserie/)) d'une chanson d'un auteur-compositeur-interprète du Québec, quel est le sens de « une bonne fois » ? C'est le « moment indéterminé dans le futur » ?

Comment: Je ne pense pas que "une bonne fois" soit courant au Québec. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu ni lu quelque part. Voici ce qu'en dit Antidote : **une bonne fois pour toutes** : Définitivement. _Ça va le faire taire une bonne fois pour toutes._

Comment: En anglais, je dirais "one of these days".

Answer (score 1):

Je ne peux identifier de source formelle indiquant spécifiquement ce que ça veut dire. Ça ressemble beaucoup à « [un beau jour](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/un_beau_jour) » soit « à une date indéterminée dans le passé ou le futur ; un certain jour » (Wiktionnaire) et ce n'est pas à mon avis l'idée que c'est fait de manière à ne jamais devoir être refait ([*une bonne fois pour toutes*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/une_bonne_fois_pour_toutes)) ni celle de pour toujours ([*une fois pour toutes*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/une_fois_pour_toutes)). En fait ça ressemble aussi à [*une fois*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/une_fois) pour « à une certaine époque ; dans une certaine occasion » comme dans l'exemple « si une fois je parviens à le découvrir » (Wiktionnaire, je comprends l'exemple comme traitant du futur...) ; ou à « une belle [fois](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois) » (que je ne connais pas mais que j'assimile à « une bonne fois ») pour *un beau jour*.

En ce qui me concerne, un locuteur québécois parmi d'autres, je comprends une référence à un futur indéterminé, à « à un moment donné/quand ça [adonnera](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/adonner) | conviendra ». Il n'est pas dans mon usage de réduire *une bonne fois pour toutes* en « une bonne fois » et les sens sont distincts (« de manière définitive » par opposition à « à un moment donné »). *La fois* peut signifier « le jour (où) » (« La fois que je t'ai rencontré à Québec » [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), référant au *Lyonnais*) et la locution adverbiale *une bonne fois* ressemble au Québec à un ajout à ce sens primaire (*un bon jour*). Ailleurs on comprendra bien ce que l'on voudra.

Answer (score 0):

« Une bonne fois » ne signifie pas « un moment indéterminé du futur ». Selon [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/fois) il n'y a aucune ambigüité, surtout aucune notion telle que « un beau jour », « une fois (à une certaine époque) ».

> **Une fois, une fois pour toutes, une bonne fois** :  décidément, définitivement.
> ♦ Je tiens à ce que j'ai une fois résolu. Si une fois je parviens à le découvrir.
> ♦ Et si le diadème une fois est à nous, Corneille, Nicom. I, 5.
> ♦ Soupirant une bonne fois pour n'avoir pas à y retourner sitôt, elle commença ainsi son histoire, Scarron, Rom. com. II, 3.
> ♦ Pour y mettre un bon ordre, une bonne fois pour toutes, Sévigné, 395.
> ♦ Je vous prie de vous désabuser une fois pour toutes de la pensée où vous êtes, Bossuet, Lett. abb. 71.
> ♦ Parlez franchement à ces messieurs une fois pour toutes, Maintenon, Lett. au card. de Noailles, 21 déc. 1701.
> ♦ Cependant voulez-vous qu'avec moins de contrainte L'un et l'autre une fois nous nous parlions sans feinte ? Racine, Brit. I, 2.
> ♦ Si ma fille une fois met le pied dans l'Aulide, Elle est morte…, Racine, Iphig. I, 1.
> ♦ Pour confondre une bonne fois une erreur si universelle, Massillon, Carême, Samar.
> ♦ Vingt fois, cent fois, mille fois pour une, se dit d'une chose qu'on a été trop souvent obligé de faire ou de dire. Je vous ai dit cela cent fois pour une, et il faut encore que je vous le répète ?

Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/une_bonne_fois_pour_toutes) fournit une entrée pour « une bonne fois pour toutes »  et asserte la synonymie de cette forme avec « une fois pour toutes » ; ce dictionnaire  met l'accent sur le côté du définitif qui fait partie de la définition du Littré.

> **De façon à ne plus devoir être refait**
> Il faut résoudre ce problème une bonne fois pour toutes : jusqu’ici, les solutions mises en œuvre n’ont jamais été à la hauteur du problème.
> Et inversement, à l’autre bout, va-t-on vraiment mourir un jour, est-ce que cela va enfin finir, une bonne fois pour toutes... comme l’on dit, une dernière bonne fois pour toutes ? — (Evelyne Grossman, L’Angoisse de penser, 2008)
> Synonymes:     définitivement,     une fois pour toutes

Le Wiktionnaire fournit aussi un entrée pour « ** une bonne fois** » ; comme le sens de cette expression, qui résulte d'une ellipse, est reconnu être synonyme de « *une bonne fois pour toutes* », toutes les expression questionnées sont équivalentes.

- Une fois, une fois pour toutes, une bonne fois, une bonne fois pour toutes

> une bonne fois   (Par ellipse) Une bonne fois pour toutes
> ♦        Avouez-le donc une bonne fois.
> ♦        Je vous le dis une bonne fois.

Le dictionnaire de l'[AC](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/fois?page=1) confirme le sens de « une fois » comme un synonyme

> **Une bonne fois, une fois pour toutes ou, ellipt., une fois** : de manière définitive.
> ♦ Décidez-vous une bonne fois.
> ♦  Vous êtes prévenu une fois pour toutes.
> ♦ Il faut pourtant que nous sachions une fois à quoi nous en tenir.

La définition du [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/une+bonne+fois+pour+toute) correspond exactement à ce qui a déjà été constaté.

> à titre définitif ; après plusieurs tentatives, une dernière fois qui devrait durer longtemps ; définitivement

Il n'y a pas de différence en Belgique : voici un extrait de [nouvelles récentes de Belgique](https://www.rtl.be/info/belgique/societe/bruxelles-a-fait-une-derniere-fete-avant-la-fermeture-des-bars-on-transmet-le-virus-une-bonne-fois-pour-toute-ca-n-a-pas-beaucoup-de-sens--1249993.aspx).

> Bruxelles a fait une "dernière fête" avant la fermeture des bars: "On transmet le virus une bonne fois pour toutes, ça n'a pas beaucoup de sens"
> "Ne croyez pas qu'on va s'arrêter"
> Du côté des jeunes, les propos sont moins mesurés. "On nous dit qu'on ne peut plus aller dans les bars, alors tout Bruxelles se bourre la gueule. On transmet le virus une bonne fois pour toutes avant de se confiner, ça n'a pas beaucoup de sens", confie l'un d'eux, qui adresse le message que tout le monde craignait aux autorités: "Ne croyez pas qu'on va s'arrêter de faire la fête parce vous dites qu'on ne peut plus le faire, on le fera simplement ailleurs, dans les appartements".

Apparemment, cette expression est aussi connue au Québec, et elle ne doit pas avoir une signification qui diffère (selon les contextes suivants).

[réf. 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUZt9olj2Zo) : Les NELK BOYS DU QUÉBEC, une bonne fois pour toutes.

[réf. 2](https://lehockeyherald.com/le-hockey-quebecois-une-bonne-fois-pour-toutes/) : Le hockey québécois, une bonne fois pour toutes !

[réf. 3](https://www.lesacdechips.com/2015/08/19/serieux-reglons-la-question-une-bonne-fois-pour-toute) : [IRONIE] Réglons la question une bonne fois pour toute

---

*Addition vu le besoin d'un plus ample examen demandé par [**user Zéhontée_Bonteuse**](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/26366/z%c3%a9hont%c3%a9e-bonteuse)*

[Jean-Pierre Ferland](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBWuuno7-rI&feature=youtu.be) : Une bonne fois, si tu veux
Je te montrerai sans tricher un côté de moi
Comme je n'ai jamais osé montrer
À qui que ce soit

Il n'y a pas de doute selon moi pour la chanson : étant donné les rapports aboutis que confirment les paroles de cette chanson, pourquoi est-ce que le personnage qui utilise « une bonne fois » remettrait l'acte de révélation dont il est question à un jours dans le futur ? Au plus, on s'attend à « un de ces jours » ; il me semble qu'il n'est question que  de parfaire cette révélation, donc que le sens est le sens habituel.

[Paroles rapportées](https://www.campingquebec.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33201&start=15&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=6967a1210702a175fd809055d23fa9c400a54357-1612431401-0-AfzwKdMGlM71vblEK7gpmv4rrj0gaZ4PCLp0kqtXpeBLDHpXDSanabRvVIjLyq54x_pJn36mP-4JXURKZ9YuB4B0W4UVpZbVpuyx1uU7nym-4sCPacZxbSyKn9F0ihJaM_ocM4altIBZT9yMsLftxs-c_1LpkdVCCPx5ycC9zRZTCklyczkyQ--ljjuMZ4nUQhBbYtrnW99-zWeRofCa4dW3l2w8MB7P56TJprARMNAYoCS-Rj8ZeaEDW4gjTwIXHMFkWXcxKAs95bVMtaYHe2dUrTKINCsLsCuVgX1Gj5KiFxMikvNTswi98O4t7uRIaR0HCHliuxPLSBgh-C1EwDoDI9cGh-mcCvnNKfypGZ3gVddpo39rDYw_eg7jqb3WqeM1HJaEGk1f8Uighh-Xppq8DMyapke8HX6QsuXcESs6) : Je travail à Joliette, je vais passé une bonne fois, pour essayer leurs café

L'orthographe est sans rapport avec le sens des mots (travaille, passé), ce qui rend la référence douteuse ; comment être sûr que le sens de « bonne fois » a été assimilé correctement ou d'une quelconque façon ?

[Mouvement Québec Français](https://quebecfrancais.org/sprechen-sie-deutsch-lallemagne-defend-sa-langue-2/) : une bonne fois aller prendre un thé ensemble et parler anglais autant qu'on voudra

Il y a peut-être un début de glissement (imperceptible) mais « autant qu'on voudra » confirme l'idée de chose faite de façon conclusive.

[VinQuébec](https://vinquebec.com/node/6637) : Je ne suis pas un expert dans la devinette des origines et cépage. D'ailleurs, j'essaie de ne pas les reconnaître. Je vous expliquerai pourquoi une bonne fois.

Il n'est pas certain que ce dilemme entre typicité et atypicité dont il est question dans l'article,  puis ce problème des identités confondues de certains crus qui y est aussi mentionné, soit l'explication de cet usage de  « une bonne fois » ; peut-être y a-t-il  glissement vers « une autre fois, plus tard » ; néanmoins, la pratique que cette interprétation exemplifie n'est  pas typique des propos de quelqu'un qui sait que ce qu'il dit n'est pas un maillon dans une chaine, n'a pas le caractère d'un discours plus ou moins périodique ; je m'en tiendrais au sens habituel.

[Rosette Laberge](https://www.quebecloisirs.com/accueil/un-printemps-ardent-fl00111639.html) :
— Entre, Suzie ! crie Agathe. Je suis dans la cuisine.
— Une bonne fois, tu vas te retrouver avec un inconnu en pleine face ! lance joyeusement Suzie. Tu ne devrais pas inviter n'importe qui à entrer chez toi comme tu le fais.

À mon avis, il n'y a aucun doute dans ce cas-ci : la formulation est elliptique (je vais te le dire une bonne fois, j'espère que tu auras compris, que je n'aurais plus à te le dire …), et ce qui suis consiste en ce qui a été annoncé : un avertissement formulé avec insistence.

[Le Cahier](https://lecahier.com/bienvenue-a-montreal-une-nouvelle-webserie/)  : Aller Au Marché Jean Talon pour sa diversité incroyable, pour les dégustations et parce qu’elle espère une bonne fois pouvoir dire à sa mère qu’elle a croisé Boucar Diouf et Francis Reddy.

Ce dernier cas n'est pas caractéristique, d'autant plus que l'adverbe n'est pas à sa place la plus habituelle : l'espérance a-t-elle été le sujet d'une bonne fois ou bien  s'agirait-il de « dire  une bonne fois »  ? Je présume que c'est « dire une bonne fois », autre chose n'ayant aucun sens. On peut se poser la question suivante : Pourquoi situer cet évènement convoité  à une date ultérieure, alors que c'est évident que cela aura lieu subséquemment puisque de toute évidence elle a des entretiens plus ou moins fréquent avec sa mère et que toute occasion convient ? Encore une fois, on ne peut trouver normal, au plus, que « un de ces jours », ce qui ne dit pas « une occasion spéciale ». L'idée de « dire une bonne fois » pour ce genre de chose qui n'est pas plus qu'une très  simple chose fait penser que la personne aurait insinué le fait à sa mère, lui aurait plus ou moins menti et qu'elle aspirerait à faire une révélation plus franche ; c'est assez bizarre.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse J'ai repris tous ces cas dans ma réponse.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Ne craignez pas de me dire franchement ce que vous pensez ; **je** chercherais à nier le régionalisme ? Ce ne serait qu'en ce qui concerne le québécois, puisqu'il est assez évident que le français belge est conforme à ce que l'on entend en France par ces expressions. Non, j'aurais reconnu clairement un nouvel usage dans cette forme (il ne s'agit que de « bonne fois » en québécois), je l'aurais souligné ; il m'importe peu que le Québec veuille suivre des voies qui s'éloignent du français métropolitain; je trouve seulement déplorable qu'un fossé soit creusé de plus en (1/2)

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse plus profond, mais après tout les français ne demandent à personne si les voies qu'ils choisissent pour leur langue conviennent à tous; alors selon quelle légitimité pourrait-je dire que le Québec doit ou adopter une pratique plutôt qu'une autre ? Je ne fais rien de cela et si vous ou quelqu'un d'autre a un argument intéressant pour me montrer qu'il existe bien un nouveau sens, je suis prêt à l'écouter. (2/2)

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Pourquoi n'auriez vous pas dû ? Il y a d'autres personnes sur ce site qui comprennent le français suffisamment pour pouvoir peut-être  arriver à un raisonnement logique qui prouverait votre point de vue exact. Il y avait il y a quelques temps une certaine user Laure qui je crois me rappeler avait pu fournir des apports intéressants en ce qui concernait vos questions. Personnellement, je n'y crois pas, mais il faut examiner plus de texte avant une conclusion une bonne fois pour toutes.

Comment: Finalement ça fait pas mal de _glissements_ et de « tout au plus _un de ces jours_ ». C'est que dans la chanson, je suis convaincu que c'est _un moment donné_ ou _un de ces jours_ justement. De plus détacher en tête de phrase l'adverbe (_définitivement_ en essence) qui se rapporterait au verbe de la proposition, et entrecouper ça d'une incise, c'est moins cohérent qu'une précision indéterminée sur le moment futur de l'action. La réponse démontre certainement que la compréhension sera nuancée selon la région du locuteur. Merci.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse C'est exact, je n'exclue pas catégoriquement la possibilité d'un glissement. Vous devriez laisser vos commentaires, ils sont instructifs dans les conclusions auxquelles on arrive en fin de discussion.

Comment: L'essence de mes commentaires à été versé dans ma réponse. Je préfère que le commentaire ne l'emportent pas sur le contenu des questions et réponses mais je comprends. En plus certains de mes commentaires sont simplement des réactions.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse All is grist to my mill!